# Rails update boolean attribute on assigning ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `has_many` association. I also have few `has_many` associations on the same model depends on boolean value. I also have a multiple select when I can choose ids of one type of association. I need to get a code: when I assign ids to association with boolean value == true then all another ids to it's association should become false.

Please consider example below:

```
class Dealer < AR::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :published_campaigns, class_name: 'Campaign', -> { where(published: true) }
  has_many :unpublished_campaigns, class_name: 'Campaign', -> { where(published: false) }
end

class Campaign
  # attribute :published, :boolean
  belongs_to :dealer
end

# code
dealer = Dealer.find(params[:id])
dealer.campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 1, 2, 3, 4
dealer.published_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 1, 2
dealer.unpublished_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 3, 4
params[:published_campaign_ids] = [2, 3]
dealer.update_attributes(published_campaign_ids: params[:published_campaign_ids]) # => true

# campaign no 2 still will be published, campaign will become published, campaign no 1 will become unpublished, and campaign no 4 still will be unpublished
dealer.campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 1, 2, 3, 4
dealer.published_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 2, 3
dealer.unpublished_campaigns.pluck(:id) # => 3, 4
```

How can I make it in a clean way?

Comment: You could use an `after_save callback`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: `after_save` is too dirty ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method added to `Dealer` to handle this like the following:

```
def setCampaigns(published, ids)
  if published
    self.published_campaign_ids = ids
    self.unpublished_campaign_ids = self.campaign_ids - ids
  else
    self.unpublished_campaign_ids = ids
    self.published_campaign_ids = self.campaign_ids - ids
  end
end
```

To use, it's simple

```
dealer.setCampaigns(true, params[:published_campaign_ids]) # to publish campaigns
```

similarly,

```
dealer.setCampaigns(false, params[:unpublished_campaign_ids]) # to unpublish campaigns
```

Comment: I had the same idea. But you should understand that these parameters will assign via mass_assignment, so it will be better to overwrite `published_campaign_ids method` in my opinion

Comment: @asiniy In this case, your logic must go somewhere, you can first call mass assignment then the function above, it'll always be one more line which I believe is clean enough. If you want, you can also change this into callbacks which isn't dirty. Instead of overriding the method callback is much more logical.